# Get and insert <ul> with jquery

Tags: jquery, lightbox

I'm hacking a Lightbox javascript image plugin to display thumbnails from a gallery on the page. The page has a series of `<img>` with a class of "gallery-image". I am gathering them and dropping them into a div in the lightbox overlay named "lb-thumbs". So I have placed this code into one of the lightbox functions:

```
var $thumbs = ($(".gallery-image").get());
$lightbox.find('.lb-thumbs').append($thumbs);
```

It works, but as soon as the lightbox opens, the original images (behind the lightbox overlay) disappear, so that when I close the lightbox, the page's original html gallery has gone. I know this is happening when the lightbox opens thanks to the browser inspector tool. So there must be something in my code that is making the `<img>` items disappear. Could it be jQuery `get()` or `append()`? I can't see where this is happening. Can you?

Thanks!
Matt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that `.get()` method returns a reference to the original array. The `.get()` is superfluous anyway. Try this:

```
var $thumbs = $(".gallery-image");
$lightbox.find('.lb-thumbs').append($thumbs);
```

You can alternately clone the array before assigning it:

```
var $thumbs = ($(".gallery-image").clone().get());
$lightbox.find('.lb-thumbs').append($thumbs);
```

Comment: The first didn't work, but the second did, although I dropped the get() from the second as you suggested. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think the append() is actually causing your problem.  When you do an append, you are not creating a new object, just pulling the old image(s) out of the DOM and re-inserting it into your lightbox.

You can always clone the objects before inserting.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/scispear/wcbqa/)**

```
$lightbox.find('.lb-thumbs').append($thumbs.clone());
```

Comment: This didn't work actually. I used the advice from the above commenter. Thanks you though.

Comment: That is true, you might not be able to clone the get().